# examine remote server certificate on server connection event mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

how can i read / examine the remote server certificate during server connection event on regular proxy mode

this is my code :
the cert attribute on documentation state as The certificate presented by the remote during the TLS handshake

```
import mitmproxy
from mitmproxy import ctx

def serverconnect(conn: mitmproxy.connections.ServerConnection):
      ctx.log.info(conn.cert)
```

[image]

the event log info always to none.... thanks for the advice and the answer

Comment: You are correct the `cert` property should contain the server certificate. But in the code I am not able to find where the cert property is set. My advice would be to run mitmproxy with attached debugger and use a break-point in your code to see what data is available using the `conn` variable.

Comment: @Robert i've been use pdb.set_trace() to debug my script and same result the cert attribute is None.... i think  tls server connection in server connection event is doesnt finish yet... i check with tls_established atribute and it returns False.... I'll try with gdb debugger and try dig deeper into the code.... I hope :)

Comment: This seems to me like a bug (or at least a misleading description) because the `serverconnect` event fires when the TCP connection to the server has been established and before the connection is converted to a TLS connection. Therefore the ServerConnection instance can never contain the server certificate...